# Neo4j session .catch error: structure (127, [[object object]])

Tags: javascript, node.js, neo4j

I am getting a .catch error "catch error: structure (127, [[object object]])" when I execute this command in nodejs. It works fine in the Neo4j browser. can anyone shed some light on this? I can't seem to find any reference to this type of error.

```
session
  .run ("MERGE (user:Visitor {name:'Visitor', email : {paramEmail}})-[:SUBMITTED_RPA {since:timestamp()}]->(rpa:RPA {name: 'RPA', email:{paramEmail},rpa_id:{paramrpa_id}, makevehicle:{parammakeVehicle},vehicledescription:{paramvehicledescription},partdescription:{parampartdescription}}) RETURN user,rpa",
        { paramEmail: newUser.email,
          parammakevehicle: newUser.makevehicle,
          paramvehicledescription: newUser.vehicledescription,
          parampartdescription: newUser.partdescription,
          paramrpa_id: newUser.rpa_id
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

The error was caused by a syntax error in the "parammakeVehicle". It should have been "parammakevehicle". This is a pretty strange error code for a syntax error.